# can't install urllib3 on raspberry pi for python3.4

Tags: python

I built python3.4 and created an alias using:

```
echo alias py="/opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4" >> .bashrc
```

and I work ok with it but when I try to use urllib3 it says it is not istalled, so I tried

```
sudo pip install urllib3
```

but when it has finished you can not use it with python3.4, so I tried to create and alias to pip3.4 as before but with pip3.4 at the end. Like this

```
echo alias pip3.4="/opt/python3.4/bin/pip3.4" >> .bashrc
```

but again I cant use urllib. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo /opt/python3.4/bin/pip3.4 install urllib3`

maybe?